# Trying to install MySQL: Package 'mysql-server' has no installation candidate

Tags: raspbian, apache-httpd, mysql

I'm trying to install MySQL; my command is:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server php-mysql -y
```

and what I'm getting is an error stating

> E: Package 'mysql-server' has no installation candidate

Comment: `sudo apt install mariadb-client mariadb-server`

Answer (score 8):

`mysql` has been replaced by `mariadb` in Debian10.

Try `default-mysql-server` - although you can use `mariadb`.

PS You can see what is available on your distribution e.g.

```
apt-cache search mysql-server
```